# What is the best way to store multiple checkbox values in the database and work with it later on

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays, checkbox

I am working on a website and i want to add a new section to it that will contain an advanced form for storing that data. There will be about 20-30 fields and few of them will be represented by multiple choice checkboxes eq array values on submit from these choices. This fields will have a fixed amount of choices that will never change and never added new ones into it. For example field one will have choice1, choice2, choice3. Field two will have 10 of them and field 3 will have 5.

Isnt a creating separate database tables for them and referencing them by its id a bit overkill? Would not it be better to save them as for example comma separated values under varchar field eq implode and eplode them every time i want to acces or store new one?

Also i have a bit trouble figuring out how to work with it later on. Since if i save them as as separate table and reference it by its id than my query will output every combiation of these fields. Which would result in for example 150 rows for one record. How can i convert it back to the single array value with nested array for this sub multiple values? for example `'id'=>1, 'title' => 'Lorem Ipsum', 'choices' => array('choice2','choice2').....`

---

update: To better illustrate what i want to do i have created a simplified mockup of the form here -> ***http://www.anony.ws/i/2013/08/13/SsD5A.gif*** Its not actual form i will be using since i did not build it yet but it is close enough. You can ignore other fields i already know how i will save or work with them later on.

What i do need some help with is that checkbox groups. I need to store selected values and later on i will need to work with them. I will need to be able to search through them i will need to be able to display that data. I will also need to be able to create some comment system (i have already done that before so basically i just need to be able to reference data from this form by its database ID. Probably some updating and or other basic stuff.

Major thing is saving this choices and searching/displaying its data. Would be really geat if i can get the data from the databse in 1 array/obect with some nested arrays for this multiple choices. Something like i have sketched in the end of this post before the update.

Comment: When faced with this scenario, I usually use a `varchar` that is a string of `1` or `0` that I can `implode` and `explode` at will.

Comment: if your choices are going to be fixed why can't you store each checkbox in separate columns in the same table?

Comment: I dont think that is a good idea because it would make searching through those records hard and the table would look like a mess.

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself the following question:
**Do I need to evaluate the choices done by the customers?**

If you do, having them in plain comma separated lists will be a very ugly operation.
If you really just want to log the choices, you can proceed with the implode/explode.

Doing it the normalized way:

Your table scheme:

```
checkbox_id | customer_id | value
```

When the customer submits his choices, you'll only insert the selected checkboxes:

```
foreach (checkbox in POST) {
    INSERT IGNORE INTO `table` (`checkbox_id`, `customer_id`, `value`) VALUES (checkbox, customer, 1)
}
```

If you want to read the customer's choices later on, go for:

```
SELECT `checkbox_id`, `value` FROM `table` WHERE `customer_id` = ? ORDER BY `checkbox_id`, `value`
```

This will get you a list of all choices done by the specified customer.
If you need them in an array, go for some function:

```
function array returnChoicesAsArray(query, checkbox_id) {
    array = [];

    foreach (row in query) {
        if (row.checkbox_id == checkbox_id)
            array.add(row.value);
    }

    return array;
}
```

and call them for each of your checkboxes.

If you want to evaluate the choices for checkboxes, you can easily query on it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` GROUP BY `checkbox_id`
```

Comment: Thank you but its still a bit unclear to me how all of this would work. Did you mean like storing it in 3 separate tables like this: checkbox avalible choices table, actual form data table and than some pivot table that would join checkbox id and form data row? If so than how would i get the whole form data back in one object? And how would i search form records based on specific values of other fields + these checkbox choices?

This is a problem that i am fighting with for a few months now and its still a bit blury picture. Joining tables is a bit confusing too but i worked with it in a past.

Comment: No, one table for all of them. You'll give each checkbox an unique ID. But I guess you need to provide an example of your checkbox markup to clarify some things. So far we can only guess what you plan to realize.

Comment: I have updated the first post, i have tried to do it as clear as i could but if you need some more info just say so.

Answer (score -3):

D'ont bother your self serialise your Array/object and store it in a simple varchar row
for example you have the following array :

$selection = array ( 'selection1'=>'value1','selection2'=>array('selectionn'=>'valuen') ....

$serialized = serialize($selection);

then store this to the database after you could retrieve the record and unserialize it to recover your entire array/Object.

Comment: "D'ont" -- that's a new one.

Comment: Did you mean like storing everything in one field? I dont think that would be good solution since i need to work with it later on. I need to be able to search through it and so on but thanks for your reply.

Comment: You can always search through it since serialised array or object is an long string

Comment: I know but i need to be able to search for specific value in specific field and that is hard to reproduce if its all in one column. And its also slower (for example integer comparison is allways faster than string).